# Itunes Search API Returns Incorrect Podcasts

Tags: api, search, itunes

I am new to the Itunes Search API... I have referenced Apple's documentation and I'm trying to retrieve podcast entries but I think I'm doing something wrong.

The following podcast author has 8 podcasts listed:  http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/dojocampus/id279440331

However, when I use the search API as http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=dojo+campus the json result file only contains 1 entry...  I cannot figure out what modification to my search API url must be made to retrieve details about all 8 podcasts in the file.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Look more closely at the JSON results:

```
"resultCount":1
```

means that the search returned 1 *album*, not 1 *track*. Later on in the entry:

```
"trackCount":8
```

tells you that the album it found (in this case the "album" of all the podcasts by this user) contains 8 separate podcasts. It's not the best method ever, but this is how their results are meant to be interpreted.

Comment: If you want to view which individual tracks are in the podcast album, check out this line `"collectionViewUrl":"http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/dojocampus/id279440331?uo=4"`

Comment: You may also want to check out Apple's official documentation for everything pertaining to the Search API: http://www.apple.com/itunesaffiliates/API/AffiliatesSearch2.1.pdf